# Converting SBML model into a simulatable Matlab Function

Tags: matlab, markup, sbml

I'm looking for a tool to convert a SBML model into a Matlab function. I've tried `SBMLTranslate()` function from libSBML but this returns a Matlab struct, not a function. Does anybody know if such  tool exists? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three efforts in this direction:

1. Frank Bergmann offers an [online service for SBML translation](http://sysbioapps.dyndns.org/Translator) where you can upload an SBML file and it will generate a MATLAB file.  The comments at the top of the generated MATLAB file explain how to use the results.  The C++ source code is [available on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/jdesigner/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Translators/MatlabTranslator/).
2. Bergmann's code referenced above was used by Stanley Gu to create [sbml2matlab](https://github.com/stanleygu/sbml2matlab), a Windows standalone program. Off-hand, I don't know whether Gu's version changed or enhanced the algorithm used by the Bergmann version, but it *seems* likely.  (Note: Gu now works at Google and does not maintain this code anymore, as far as I know.)
3. The [Systems Biology Format Converter (SBFC)](http://sbfc.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a framework written principally by Nicolas Rodriguez; it includes a collection of converters, one of which is an [SBML-to-MATLAB converter](http://sbfc.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php/SBML2Matlab). This converter is written in Java.

I have not compared the results of the translators myself yet, so cannot speak to the differences or quality of output.  If you try them and have any feedback to relate, *please* let the authors know.  Knowing what has or hasn't worked for real users will help improve things in the future.

A final caveat is that all of these have been research projects, so make sure to set your expectations accordingly.  (This is not a criticism of the authors; the authors are very good – I know most of them personally – but the reality of academic development work is that we all lack the time and resources to make these systems comprehensive, hardened, polished, and documented to the degree that we wish we could.)